# Why doesn't Pandas use the same memory block for reading into the same Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I read a big CSV file into a Dataframe in a Jupyter notebook with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(my_file)

df.info()
> memory usage: 10.7+ GB
```

When I execute the same cell again, the total memory usage of my system increases. And after I repeat a few times, Jupyter kernel eventually dies.

I would expect Python to release the memory before loading new data to the same variable, or release the memory once it finishes loading. Why does the memory usage increases more and more? How can I make Python return that memory back to the system?

Comment: `del df`. Note: probably you are using some result, and it is possible that python keep the df in memory just for few data it need (indices, etc.). In such case, when you have done, just copy the result (`.copy()`) so you detach results from df

Answer (score 1):

In this case as @Giacoma Catenazzi explained in his comment. Ipykernel the kernel behind the Jupyters Notebooks, KEEPS EVERY SINGLE VARIABLE IN MEMORY. Until you explicitly tell to clear it is space. That is partially one of the main reasons.

But why does it increase?

Well the basic idea behind it, is you are using procedural logic of code like in Jupyters and you are trying to formulate specific logics that will probably run one after another. You will most of the time never rerun the same cell over and over again, specially if a succeeding variable is dependent of the variable being loaded ("which I think is your case").

So if you are working with great quantities of data it is recommended to either use, the `copy` statement or the `del` statement.

More about del:

Del is gonna COMPLETELY clear the space in memory that your current variable is using.
You can see more about the del statement in [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/del) website

More about copy:

It copies your dataframe indices and data, depending of certain given parameters. It possibilitates a change in a dataframe, that will affect all the suceding dataframe without having to restart the kernel, more about it in the [documents](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)